# Tika Server - Parse without bookmark and image tags

Tags: apache-tika, tika-server

I am extracting text with `tika server v1.20`.

Tika adds [bookmark: xx] and [image: xx] in the text. I don't want them.

Sample output:

> How the Gifted Brain Learns
>   David A. Sousa
>   **[image: How the Gifted Brain Learns]**
>   Welcome to our Third Annual GATE Family Book Study.

Reproduce:

run server -

```
java -jar tika-server-1.20.jar -p 5000
```

PUT `http://localhost:5000/tika`

Attach file as binary and `content-type`: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

Input file: http://www.hasd.org/cms_files/resources/website%20book%20study%20how%20the%20brain%20works%20building%20background1.docx

Removing this tags using regex`\[(image:|bookmark:).*?\]` is proplematic because of cases like this:

```
[image: **[1].jpg]
```

How to use tika server and do not produce this tags?
If not possible, how to remove them?

Comment: Ask for the XHTML version instead of the plain text one, then skip those tags before you grab the text out?

Comment: Getting the xhtml version makes me extract the text from it. It adds another processing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you can override this in Tika by adding a custom *DocumentSelector* for the *EmbeddedDocumentUtil* to use in the ParseContext, there is nothing like that in tika-config.xml at the moment, nor on it's command line parameters.

As an aside, there is a header setting for the Recursive Metadata endpoint coming up in Tika 1.25 which lets you specify the maximum embedded recursion (see blow example). However, as you want the content this doesn't help in your case:

```
curl -T test_recursive_embedded.docx --header "maxEmbeddedResources: 0" http://localhost:9998/rmeta
```

Depending on what part of the content you are looking to process, there is an endpoint that may be what you are looking for. This is the */tika/main* endpoint.

```
curl -T website\ book\ study\ how\ the\ brain\ works\ building\ background1.docx http://localhost:9998/tika/main --header "Accept: text/plain"
```

This aims to replicate the Tika App's *--text-main* function and uses the Boilerplate content handler that focuses on the main content in a file. This therefore doesn't process the embedded images.